# Basic scoped timer struct (extensively redesigned)

Tags: c++, library, timer, c++20, constrained-templates

Here is the [original question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283026/basic-scoped-timer-struct-design). I have extensively revised and redesigned my custom scoped timer for my needs using the feedback I got from two helpful members of this community. However I was told to ask a new question in case I want my new solution to be reviewed.

Here is the revised version ([live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5TKALEBjA9gEwKYFFMCWALugE4A0BIEAZgQDbYB2AhgLbYgDkAjF%2BTXRMiAZVQtGIHgBYBQogFUAztgAKAD24AGfgCsp5eiyahUAUgBMAIUtXyKxqiIEh1ZpgDC6egFc2TA3cAGQImbAA5PwAjbFIDAAd0JWIXJi9ffwSklKEQsMi2GLiee2xHZyERIhZSInS/AJKHbCdUqpqiPIjo2IMlatr6zKaBztDuwt6eAEp7dB9SVE4uMy0AQUsAZlDUXxwAajNNj1QkUiF0I9xVjYttpl2fA6OPIgBPeOwAfSJSFmIlFcblsdntsIdjj5nPRiG8gesQQ8wRCPDQfA8Kqx6PDbvdHs9jkQztgWJgcYj8eCXqh%2BoRLptrgi7qCnlTjjQ2EQAPQYUjYAB0SHJzKRrJRHO5p3OTHQgvJCPWRGwbHiRiVKP2uxYSiU%2BwAIgsWJiIXr9rSQGgzhcLWwCKhzioMExMEpyMCtABOVYe/a%2BrU6/YeejoVAAa19vqOpvNlul6At/RJmDeX12IfDOL5AEcfAQ%2BbqIGaiJgLVLrSACEpU8Gw18AG4vIPpq6HCwANksHfWEZ7PezufzhwA7FYiyXY%2BXnBwvolQkRGzXQ%2BR9YbMUCR8O9UdR2Yh6bpjd%2BqQfE5DgBWGwX/YywhKcSkTDnrdn01idCfTAAFQIHFIwJHNw9j4yQmJqi69j2UaBou26ARGwGhMA%2ByYKuqQQVBBp/Gumw2N28EgUhfLxBBvYYahrggERsF4b6CGgZ8pAuI%2BJFkVhqQWgxTHUWsQEEfsU7fLOwiQZs0bFqWVoyhaAkzugc4Lumy6YUaqRAjhcG0Xx4j0PQUQsLW7yfCaY4WqSmCyXOsQ/C8dZyY%2BhbKca0zXug2DqEs8Tzgy3EaUWKmoF82oqLUhYxpWXwykS5wAO5fKEtniFEjBfKQ9Y2XZy7abp%2Bmhj8HzYMuKFsUILYHupCobJ6MlCUQmpCP0fm1MOo4ytFhbObuW7lZVHpZXpBn5ZqEjZWGPk0fsbmqnaxD7G%2BH7fr%2BhZ9TleVGU6DVZV8/UZqJ14%2BDpnmkPszkym5HlEIWp3udgnmXegbXHY9B4Kj6EYgENOnbc1H30FtOWbu6XoAS9nXujxEZzdgX4/rES31bVkPQ7%2Bnb7KQSC6h1u04DQLD7V5uGVeDvqIwtsOzRg80w3%2B7Yo2jGMuWdN3zuNPbvf0HSQRuMZsOgdbYIWdP8uzTUdXubos72y1ht9MZnUgxjAPzqPo/yUtLntB2/I9oPjbuBOc1uFXegAfiTVPtYDeu%2BT2BA0PsS3DV9UZQUw%2B30Idx3WyRfJEAsTBjUTva23VTCJuo8RHXdjO3S5D3OfHXuRsDgckSHDXVXJwnuN9rXtQD3Wpz2YVMLZobfH%2Bxy2QQZIMg7n05cu2cALSNbVZX6yxe6JxN9AqN3VsSxBvxwoPpHJ4XJHrbVGdzhNzo5/deegwXE%2B9sXpfl%2Bl1dXHXI3q83reeyvE86ynk9Gqc9v7PyN/axup%2Bp6f3pP7rF5mFeN6Vvej7v8%2BppFSpEq40ygsHiCocyAk85TxRldc6Udrox1zk9T2utx7e2wL7UgTBY55xbsLfGvkX6B3fpeFqWAv41B/i%2BX%2B/EYYWWEuzZw5hxpIJOq5BBF0GYcKWouC0rCnqELQRBH2fsTITikiAGewhUzai8h4AB2FcA8PTHwxeAjj4AwRF3bqYM6JIRjGWGUXwYRKj%2BL3C075YhGjIJYCwti2CAh0YqZUqojRshOEYAMjlUiZU8bqJso1vLrDNsjY43ihDLgCaGFsaIHiFhCbEF44SmCRJggyWhv4UEbCERk2IqtHb/SgiQ3%2BcNQ61VxiQZC5FsFsOjszM%2Bq9OYd0aRPYe3cWkRgHg0jpJEJQcUYsIUKxZYgUFbHYs8HgmCkyOqEfYsTUD8XQOgDMAEu4TP9hYCwhVqlH2aT09CXdR77PEEQS%2BhYb78jvjuQ53SWnLwJr5GMRJwpRSTAmRgN0viCFIIWCwWgtAON2WDPsGDRECQrg8m5NxZ5sH%2BEwC2Wi9kJKOuC76xSXylIahU9AVTio1K4eddpPSun7MaW0o5pKk57MpRPPpIAI5ziGTgUgozbHv0mdMxZyzmqg3WbY7ZeKgUUspQ/GlqcTlnOvrfUW1zDa3OJXufODzxpPKQC84kpJ3nYE%2Bd8wsPB/mAvbsCiGFMoacoIRVHs2L%2BIWGMvMplNpeZK1RQnJxgciD5PrtLIpb8MVp1qgYyS8YQC2ntEkFoQgXTIUerApmPLhW9M5P0xlY4RnLjZes81XKVk2DWZM/l0b25KuNb6VV6q%2BSapAEoD58QvlkELGeA1GMfI3K4LMeg3Azz8ACFwHQ5B4xcA8LYWwZp5iLCpHcPg5AiDaDbbMUMIAhzSH5EOCw0hpBtiHJsLQmxpBnk2JsM8hhuDSH4GwEAjbyA9r7QO/gSgQBaGnbO2YcBYAoDci0KEZBKDUBqMAJQqhjBlBEEge6Pap0YBVAwQBTBANhHoCBsDs7yCQfiAwXowAeCbJQ%2BgKDjBSAAHkoSIeite/gH7UBrFIP%2B7g5H1AtCqIQHt/BBDCDEBITgMg5DCGUGoTQva9AGCMCYNAw7rCGAIFEe9sBWAcBABKcgfM4hcA9Pqud/bPKpHvVwJutIozmGsLYO4%2Bwm4Ec2CZgA6sNSzblfgsEsx%2BYwTDLNKHlpge6lmnRKeSEIFzBBgBMCbl52IPnsFN08hqzAd6x1LD6MWUIcHgOgdI9wKdvxtWpf4NFP48RMvts7d25DA7cD0dQF%2Bo66gAAcbYm5tmkPsYAqAFlYf5LaiAQ7DPif2PgYgZBWybBmPwGdAnpizCQEmXoEB50gAsGeVrQ4zz7vbB6NsZ4N2raPR2rgp6r1Fdo/YB9T6Rv5a4BYM9i6eD8m3ZV1d0hKubE2TIIcbZdsCf7ft4bOgX2IAgCgVD6GKBUAgP9/DIBMPYZwHWO02AABqBBsDRQI58cDLGGCmPvRAKIyGoihBqG8TL5AcesFIG8AjURdAtGGxB3DHBhAEaYPQfHb2cCwpMJIZneZKcED5tpvtFGoTLCnZZLbfaYRRD%2BCTrwOBkO/B/HlgQRh/1w4R0j5gBPWOiG0px2QGveMaGQ/oEownTBibsGL6TUBZOcAU0p7gqmvuzHfJibTuniz6dN8Z0z5mm5WZ0jZ9QdmHNQyc3aFzbmPM%2B%2BC6QULfmAtBaEN5tC4XXmkjvWULnrgIDuCGI0cgwRxgFCKFkZImIc/F5yEwLohepilHKG0UYZemjp9aJUUYVeejFHsA37wDQ4sdHb5MYoswlAxc4ydrtr2b3cH2FVmrdWGtNf2C1trPWSBHS2INo7DvyDjdJJNk7O3z0WEq/yNsqmLALZ4JuoclWzx3Be2R97XA72Hc%2B%2BprbmxCtvdvVv9TifXDSBAA%3D%3D%3D)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

#include <thread>       // only needed for client code
#include <cstdio>       // ditto
#include <fmt/core.h>   // ditto
#include <fmt/chrono.h> // ditto


template < class Duration = std::chrono::microseconds,
           class Clock    = std::chrono::steady_clock >
requires ( std::chrono::is_clock_v<Clock> &&
           requires { std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>{ }; } )
struct [[ nodiscard ]] ScopedTimer
{
    using clock         = Clock;
    using duration      = Duration;
    using rep           = Duration::rep;
    using period        = Duration::period;
    using time_point    = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>;
    using callback_type = std::add_pointer_t<void ( Duration ) noexcept>;

    static_assert( std::is_nothrow_invocable_r_v<void, callback_type, duration> );

    time_point const start { now( ) };
    callback_type callback;

    explicit ScopedTimer( callback_type const call_back = nullptr ) noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) )
        : callback { call_back }
    {
    }

    ScopedTimer( const ScopedTimer& rhs ) = default;

    ScopedTimer( ScopedTimer&& rhs ) noexcept
        : start    { std::move( rhs.start ) },
          callback { std::exchange( rhs.callback, nullptr ) }
    {
    }

    ~ScopedTimer( )
    {
        if ( callback == nullptr )
            return;

        if constexpr ( noexcept( now( ) ) )
        {
            const time_point end { now( ) };
            std::invoke_r<void>( callback, end - start );
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                const time_point end { now( ) };
                std::invoke_r<void>( callback, end - start );
            }
            catch ( ... ) { }
        }
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] duration
    elapsed_time( ) const& noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) )
    {
        return now( ) - start;
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] time_point static
    now( ) noexcept( noexcept( clock::now( ) ) )
    {
        return std::chrono::time_point_cast<duration>( clock::now( ) );
    }
};


// --------------------- client code e.g. in Main.cpp -----------------------

using std::chrono_literals::operator""ms;

template <class Duration, class Clock>
ScopedTimer<Duration, Clock> func( ScopedTimer<Duration, Clock> timer )
{
    timer.callback = []( const auto duration ) noexcept
                     {
                        try
                        {
                            fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer in func took {}\n", duration );
                        }
                        catch ( ... ) { }
                     };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 200ms );

    return timer;
}

int main( )
{
    ScopedTimer timer { []( const auto duration ) noexcept
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer took {}\n", duration );
                            }
                            catch ( ... ) { }
                        } };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );

    ScopedTimer t;

    auto t2 = func( std::move( timer ) ); // timer is now moved-from, so
                                          // its dtor won't invoke its callback

    t.callback = []( const std::chrono::microseconds d ) noexcept {
                  fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer t took {}\n", d ); };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 500ms );
}
```

**Notable changes from the previous solution:**

1. `ScopedTimer` now has a *move* and a *copy* constructor that behave as I expect. The *move* constructor assigns `nullptr` to the `callback` member of the moved-from object so whenever its destructor is called, it checks the `callback` member and if it's `nullptr` then it realizes that `*this` has been moved from and that it should not invoke its *callback function*. With that said, I could not implement the *assignment operators* apparently because the `start` member is `const` so it cannot be reassigned in the assignment operators.
2. It now has several `using` declarations for the *typenames* that are used by the struct (similar to classes in std library) so that the client code can have easy access to these typenames if needed.
3. Added a `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to the struct's declaration so that the compiler gives warnings whenever a `ScopedTimer` instance returned from a function is ignored.
4. Defined (and thus restricted) the `callback_type` as a pointer type to a function that takes a `duration` and return `void` and must be `noexcept`.
5. Used a static assertion to make sure that the `callback_type` is `nothrow`-invocable. However, I'm not sure whether this assertion is redundant or not.
6. Assigned `nullptr` (as the default argument) to the `call_back` parameter of the constructor so that the client code can create an object without passing a callback pointer to the constructor (i.e. default construction is possible).
7. Used `std::invoke_r` to invoke the callback inside the destructor.
8. Added a non-static member function that retrieves the elapsed time when called which can come in handy for some purposes.
9. The `now()` function is declared as a `static` member function since it doesn't access any non-static members of the struct.
10. Because the `callback_type` requires it, any callback function passed to a `ScopedTimer` object needs to be marked as `noexcept`. This requirement exists because the `callback` will be invoked inside the destructor so it should not throw. This puts the responsibility on the client code to make sure that any exceptions thrown inside the passed callback function are properly handled.

Regarding the above snippet, I have defined a sample function named `func` that represents how a `ScopedTimer` object (`ScopedTimer timer`) can be moved/copied to different functions and that they can return it to their call site. Also it is shown that a `ScopedTimer` object (`ScopedTimer t;`) can be default-constructed (i.e. without specifying a callback) and then be assigned a callback at a later stage.

**With all that said, three things still bother me:**

- Firstly, in case `now()` throws inside the destructor, it is caught by a catch-all clause and ignored. I could not find an easy way to pass the exception (or maybe its `std::exception_ptr`) to the call site where the `ScopedTimer` object was created. Is this really an issue? I guess if done correctly, it could increase the code correctness;
- Secondly, my current implementation of the `ScopedTimer::callback_type` doesn't allow lambda expressions that have a non-empty capture clause (e.g. `[&]` or `[=]`). Those types of capture clauses could be useful for the client code in some ways. But my current code does not compile when those capture clauses are used. I have discovered a new C++23 class template called [std::move_only_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) which probably could be used as the `callback_type` (e.g. `using callback_type = std::move_only_function<void ( Duration ) const noexcept>;`) to solve this issue.
- Thirdly, I would like to prevent *prvalue* objects from calling `elapsed_time()` since it will always result in a 0 as a duration being returned (e.g. 0 ms). I mean semantically it does not make much sense if a prvalue object calls that member function. Can this be restricted?

***As always, any further suggestions are appreciated.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's great to see the improvements you made! Almost all of them make sense and improve the quality and usability of the class.

## Using `std::function` to store the callback

Your `callback_type` is just a plain old pointer-to-function. As you mentioned, that's indeed unfortunate, as this limits what kind of callbacks you can pass. So ideally we want:

```
using callback_type = std::function<void(Duration)>;
```

But then your code won't compile any more, which is probably why you went for the function pointer. The big issue is that `Duration` is a template parameter, and `std::function<void(Duration)>` is a dependent type, and a lambda does not have the same type as a `std::function`, so when you pass a lambda to the constructor, the compiler has no idea what to do with it.

A [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) might help here. The easiest is just to add this after the definition of `class ScopedTimer`:

```
template<typename T>
ScopedTimer(T) -> ScopedTimer<>;
```

This will cause a statement like:

```
ScopedTimer t([](auto duration){…});
```

to compile, and `Duration` to have the default value (`std::chrono::microseconds`). The drawback is that there is no deduction on the type of the parameter of the lambda, so the following won't compile:

```
ScopedTimer t([](std::chrono::seconds duration){…});
```

But then again, that didn't seem to work with your version either. Another drawback is that you cannot have a `std::function` that is `noexcept`, but see below.

Since you deleted the copy constructor, the only thing you will ever do with `callback`, besides calling it, is to move from it in the move constructor. So indeed with C++23 you could use [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function) to store the callback, as this will allow even more types of functions to be stored. The drawback of course is that C++23 is not finished yet, and it might take a few more years before compilers and standard libraries have full support for it, but you can use `#if __cpp_lib_move_only_function` to test for it.

## Consider removing `noexcept`

I think it's not worth making everything `noexcept` and catching exceptions in the destructor. You should keep it for the move constructor, but that's about it.

Consider that someone might do more in the callback than just print a message. Maybe they want to unlock a mutex, commit a transaction to a database, or something else that is important and should not cause the program to hide failure.

Note that if you want to keep `noexcept`, you should ask yourself why you require the callback function to be `noexcept`, but allow `Clock::now()` to throw. And if you are going to catch all exceptions in the destructor anyway, why not allow the callback to throw, as the exception won't escape the destructor then?

## Preventing prvalues from calling `elapsed_time()`

> I would like to prevent prvalue objects from calling `elapsed_time()` since it will always result in a 0 as a duration being returned (e.g. 0ms).

You can do it by adding a deleted overload with an [rvalue ref-qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#member_functions_with_ref-qualifier):

```
void elapsed_time( ) const&& = delete;
```

## Make the member variables `private`

I would make the member variables `private`. Especially if you worry about things like prvalue objects calling `elapsed_time()`, I don't think you want to allow any code to accidentally modify `start` and/or `callback`. If you really want to make that possible, consider adding member functions to do such modifications, perhaps like a `reset()` to reset the timer. This makes things more explicit.

## Unnecessary use of `std::invoke_r()`

The functions `std::invoke()` and `std::invoke_r()` are mainly useful if you have no idea what the type of the function object you pass it is, for example in the case of:

```
template<typename Func, typename Arg>
auto call_with_argument(Func&& func, Arg&& arg) {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}
```

Because writing `return func(arg)` might not be valid if `func` is a pointer-to-member-function or pointer-to-data-member. But you know exactly what the type of `callback` is: it's a `void (*)(Duration)` (or `std::function<void(Duration)>` with my suggested change). So writing:

```
callback(end - start);
```

Is guaranteed to be perfectly valid. You are also sure that the return value is `void`, so no need to cast it to void again using `std::invoke_r<void>()`.

While it's not wrong to use `std::invoke_r()` here, it is more complicated than necessary, and gives the idea that something special is going on here that necessitates its use.

Comment: Thanks again! And regarding the `callback_type` issue and the `std::function` based solution you suggested, I have just discovered the new `std::move_only_function` class of C++23. Please check the question's last section again since I have made an edit and provided a link to the docs. I will test it tomorrow to see if it can help.

Comment: Your deduction guide works well. BTW, here in `template<typename T> ScopedTimer(T) -> ScopedTimer<>;` what exactly does T represent? Can we call it `template <typename Callback>` to make it more clear?

Comment: Also is there a way we can deduce the `Duration` template parameter from the given callback that is passed to the ctor? As you mentioned, the deduction guide does not work in cases that don't use the `auto` keyword: "*The drawback is that there is no deduction on the type of the parameter of the lambda*..."

Comment: That's a good question, but you can't. You can write `template<typename T> ScopedTimer(std::function<void(T)>) -> ScopedTimer<T>`, but it wouldn't match, because any lambda you are passing in is not a `std::function` to begin with. And unfortunately [there is no way to deduce the type of argument from a lambda's type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47255494/5481471), especially not if the lambda itself is a generic one. Writing `Callback` instead of `T` in the working deduction guide is clearer.

Comment: I found this answer on SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43526780/13407802) that shows a way on how to retrieve the type of the first parameter of a fucntion. Do you think this can be used to retrieved the type of the first parameter of a callback lambda so that it can be used in a single all-purpose deduction guide? Like in `template <class Callback> ScopedTimer( Callback ) -> ScopedTimer<FirstParam<decltype(Callback)>::type>;`. Or it still won't be useful for lambdas?

Comment: That only works for regular function pointers, not for lambdas. Although now that I think about it, you can cast a lambda to a function pointer (for example, using the unary `+` operator), but only if it doesn't have captures, and if it isn't a generic lambda of course, because how could you deduce the argument type from `[](auto duration){…}`?

Comment: So that solution provided in that answer is not useful for every type of lambda expressions. Right? Then I will only keep your suggested deduction guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the valuable feedback from *G. Sliepen*, I came up with yet another slighly improved solution.

Here is my revised version ([live on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jn5178d9a)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <exception>
#include <utility>

#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>


template < class Duration = std::chrono::microseconds,
           class Clock    = std::chrono::steady_clock >
requires ( std::chrono::is_clock_v<Clock> &&
           requires { std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>{ }; } )
struct [[ nodiscard ]] ScopedTimer
{
    using clock         = Clock;
    using duration      = Duration;
    using rep           = Duration::rep;
    using period        = Duration::period;
    using time_point    = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>;
    using callback_type = std::conditional_t< noexcept( Clock::now( ) ),
                                              std::move_only_function<void ( Duration ) noexcept>,
                                              std::move_only_function<void ( Duration,
                                                                             std::exception_ptr ) noexcept> >;

    time_point const start { now( ) };
    callback_type callback;

    explicit ScopedTimer( callback_type&& call_back = nullptr ) noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) )
        : callback { std::move( call_back ) }
    {
    }

    ScopedTimer( ScopedTimer&& rhs ) noexcept
        : start    { std::move( rhs.start ) },
          callback { std::move( rhs.callback ) }
    {
    }

    ~ScopedTimer( )
    {
        if ( callback == nullptr )
            return;

        if constexpr ( noexcept( now( ) ) )
        {
            const time_point end { now( ) };
            callback( end - start );
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                const time_point end { now( ) };
                callback( end - start, nullptr );
            }
            catch ( ... )
            {
                const std::exception_ptr ex_ptr { std::current_exception( ) };
                callback( duration { }, ex_ptr );
            }
        }
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] duration
    elapsed_time( ) const& noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) )
    {
        return now( ) - start;
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] duration
    elapsed_time( ) const&& noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) ) = delete;

    [[ nodiscard ]] time_point static
    now( ) noexcept( noexcept( clock::now( ) ) )
    {
        return std::chrono::time_point_cast<duration>( clock::now( ) );
    }
};

template <class Callback>
ScopedTimer( Callback ) -> ScopedTimer<>;


using std::chrono_literals::operator""ms;

template <class Duration, class Clock>
ScopedTimer<Duration, Clock> func( ScopedTimer<Duration, Clock> timer )
{
    std::exception_ptr ex_ptr;

    timer.callback = [ &ex_ptr ]( const auto duration ) noexcept
                     {
                        try
                        {
                            fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer in func took {}\n", duration );
                        }
                        catch ( ... )
                        {
                            ex_ptr = std::current_exception( );
                        }
                     };

    if ( ex_ptr )
    {
        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception( ex_ptr );
        }
        catch ( const std::exception& ex )
        {
            fmt::print( stderr, "{}\n", ex.what( ) );
        }
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 200ms );

    return timer;
}

int main( )
{
    std::move_only_function<void ( std::chrono::milliseconds ) noexcept> f =
        [&]( const auto duration ) noexcept
        {
            try
            {
                fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer took {}\n", duration );
            }
            catch ( ... ) { }
        };

    ScopedTimer<std::chrono::milliseconds> timer { std::move( f ) };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );

    ScopedTimer t;

    auto t2 = func( std::move( timer ) );

    t.callback = []( const auto d ) noexcept {
                  fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer t took {}\n", d ); };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 500ms );
}
```

So basically, the client code can now pass in different callback types including lambda expressions that have non-empty capture clauses.

And more importantly, the code now forces the client code to provide a callback type that also has an extra parameter of type `std::exception_ptr` (only forced when the provided `class Clock` is non-trivial, e.g. `std::chrono::gps_clock`) so that whenever a non-trivial clock's `now()` method throws inside the destructor, the pointer to the caught exception is passed to the callback and the callback is responsible to handle it properly. This way, all the exceptions can be caught and dealt with at the call site (e.g. by using a `[&ex_ptr]` capture clause in order to copy the exception's pointer to the call site and then do a `std::rethrow_exception(ex_ptr)` there) as shown in the function `func` in the above snippet.

Comment: @G. Sliepen Please have a look at my final solution here.

Comment: Gladly, if you post it as a new question :)

Comment: @G. Sliepen I think I have asked enough questions for this same piece of code and thus I've been able to greatly redesign the solution. So maybe I need to stop being too pedantic and end the journey here. I'm going to add this solution to my actual project and commit the changes. So anyway, thank you a ton for your help and collaboration.

Comment: It's not a problem to post yet another version, you are far from breaking the record on this site for the most posted questions on the same code. I'll just mention that you can default the move constructor now. Good luck with your actual project :)

Comment: @G. Sliepen Yet another improvement! Thanks. That one didn't come to my mind.