# scoped timer class (3rd revision)

Tags: c++, library, timer, template-meta-programming, c++23

Again, here is the [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283104/basic-scoped-timer-struct-extensively-redesigned). I have (re)revised my custom scoped timer using the valuable feedback I got from a helpful member of this community. However I feel the need to ask this question so that my new solution is reviewed.

Here is the code ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/x9dzW9bjh)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <exception>
#include <utility>

// these are only required by client code
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>


#define NODISCARD_WARNING_MSG "ignoring returned value of type 'ScopedTimer' might " \
                              "change the program's behavior since it has side effects"


template < class Duration = std::chrono::microseconds,
           class Clock    = std::chrono::steady_clock >
requires ( std::chrono::is_clock_v<Clock> &&
           requires { std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>{ }; } )
class [[ nodiscard( NODISCARD_WARNING_MSG ) ]] ScopedTimer
{
public:
    using clock         = Clock;
    using duration      = Duration;
    using rep           = Duration::rep;
    using period        = Duration::period;
    using time_point    = std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>;
    using callback_type = std::conditional_t< noexcept( Clock::now( ) ),
                                              std::move_only_function<void ( Duration ) noexcept>,
                                              std::move_only_function<void ( Duration,
                                                                             std::exception_ptr ) noexcept> >;

    [[ nodiscard( "implicit destruction of temporary object" ) ]] explicit
    ScopedTimer( callback_type&& callback = nullptr ) noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) )
        : m_callback { std::move( callback ) }
    {
    }

    [[ nodiscard( "implicit destruction of temporary object" ) ]]
    ScopedTimer( ScopedTimer&& rhs ) noexcept = default;

    ~ScopedTimer( )
    {
        if ( m_callback == nullptr )
            return;

        if constexpr ( noexcept( now( ) ) )
        {
            const time_point end { now( ) };
            m_callback( end - m_start );
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                const time_point end { now( ) };
                m_callback( end - m_start, nullptr );
            }
            catch ( ... )
            {
                const std::exception_ptr ex_ptr { std::current_exception( ) };
                m_callback( duration { }, ex_ptr );
            }
        }
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] const time_point&
    get_start( ) const& noexcept
    {
        return m_start;
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] const time_point&
    get_start( ) const&& noexcept = delete;

    [[ nodiscard ]] const callback_type&
    get_callback( ) const& noexcept
    {
        return m_callback;
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] const callback_type&
    get_callback( ) const&& noexcept = delete;

    void
    set_callback( callback_type&& callback ) & noexcept
    {
        m_callback = std::move( callback );
    }

    void
    set_callback( callback_type&& callback ) && noexcept = delete;

    [[ nodiscard ]] duration
    elapsed_time( ) const& noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) )
    {
        return now( ) - m_start;
    }

    [[ nodiscard ]] duration
    elapsed_time( ) const&& noexcept( noexcept( now( ) ) ) = delete;

    [[ nodiscard ]] time_point static
    now( ) noexcept( noexcept( clock::now( ) ) )
    {
        return std::chrono::time_point_cast<duration>( clock::now( ) );
    }

private:
    time_point const m_start { now( ) };
    callback_type m_callback;
};

template <class Callback>
ScopedTimer( Callback&& ) -> ScopedTimer<>;

template <class Duration>
ScopedTimer( std::move_only_function<void ( Duration ) noexcept> ) -> ScopedTimer<Duration>;


// --------------------------- client code ---------------------------

using std::chrono_literals::operator""ms;

template <class Duration, class Clock>
ScopedTimer<Duration, Clock> func( ScopedTimer<Duration, Clock> timer )
{
    std::exception_ptr ex_ptr;

    timer.set_callback( [ &ex_ptr ]( const auto duration ) noexcept
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer in func took {}\n", duration );
                            }
                            catch ( ... )
                            {
                                ex_ptr = std::current_exception( );
                            }
                        } );

    if ( ex_ptr )
    {
        try
        {
            std::rethrow_exception( ex_ptr );
        }
        catch ( const std::exception& ex )
        {
            fmt::print( stderr, "{}\n", ex.what( ) );
        }
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 200ms );

    return timer;
}

int main( )
{
    std::move_only_function<void ( std::chrono::milliseconds ) noexcept> f =
        [&]( const auto duration ) noexcept
        {
            try
            {
                fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer took {}\n", duration );
            }
            catch ( ... ) { }
        };

    ScopedTimer timer { std::move( f ) };

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 100ms );

    ScopedTimer t;

    auto t2 = func( std::move( timer ) );

    t.set_callback( []( const auto d ) noexcept {
                    fmt::print( stderr, "\nTimer t took {}\n", d ); } );

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( 500ms );
}
```

**Chnages**:

1. I have added 3 `[[nodiscard(message)]]` attributes to the code. Although I'm not sure how the one for move constructor might be useful. No valid scenario comes to my mind.
2. I also added setters and getters for members `m_start` and `m_callback` and also deleted their rvalue reference overloads.
3. Used the `class` keyword instead of `struct` and thus made the two member variables private.
4. Added a second template deduction guide so that the type parameter `Duration` can be deduced from the *duration parameter type* of the `std::move_only_function` object that is passed to the constructor of `ScopedTimer`.

Any suggestions could be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you reached all your goals with this class, and you implemented all the suggestions I made, so I don't have much to say about it anymore. You could consider adding some more utility functions. For example, a `cancel()` function that removes the callback and returns the (discardable) elapsed time. Or `pause()` and `continue()` functions. But the [YAGNI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) applies here.

The only issue I see with this code is that it looks overengineered, and it now relies on C++23, which means that not a lot of codebases will be able to use it yet.

Comment: It's good to hear this all. And no, I'm only going to use this class in one of my open source hobby projects so it's fine that it's relying on C++23 support.

Comment: And do think that the `cancel()` function could be named as `ditch_callback()` or maybe `discard_callback()`?

Comment: `unset_callback()` or `reset_callback()` might be better names. Although you can always do `set_callback(nullptr)` to get the same effect.

Comment: Yeah `unset_callback()` sounds better to me. And of course set_callback(nullptr) can do that but it doesn't return the elapsed time so I think it's good to implement the unset_callback.

Comment: Do you know why using the explicit keyword for the move ctor causes a compile error?

Comment: I have no idea. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6758717/5481471) might be of some help, but it also doesn't explain why it fails to compile then.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I now know why it fails to compile. Thanks.

Comment: And one last little question I forgot to ask: in the first deduction guide `template <class Callback>
ScopedTimer( Callback&& ) -> ScopedTimer<>;` I added `&&` to the parameter to make it a universal reference. Is this better than not having `&&`? Cause I feel like a universal reference makes more sense here.

Comment: I don't think it matters: the deduction guide is only used to determine which template parameters to use, once that is known it will call the actual constructor. If your constructor has only one form, then using the same one in the deduction guide is not bad though :)